# Magento2 composer update issue

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module

I have installed one module with composer and that module stored in vendor folder.

Now i do not need that module, I have deleted from it and run the commnad "composer update"

Still i can see the module stored in vendor,

How to remove it completely, my site is down now.

Answer (score 1):

you should have run that command to remove the extension :

`composer remove company/module-pacakge`

While you install module using composer there are 2 files where entries are added :

1 - composer.json

2 - composer.lock

if you have deleted the module manually then, you should delete entries in both files of that module and then run composer update

Comment: where does i find 1 - composer.json

2 - composer.lock files?

Comment: root folder of your project.

Comment: i used composer remove company/module-pacakge, but i am getting like this
Dependency "composer/composer" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.

Comment: like what ? did you tried with other option remove entries from files ?

Comment: i used remove using composer but not working

Comment: i did that, now i am getting error like Please update your modules: Run \"composer install\" from the Magento root directory

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command will remove the package from vendor (or wherever you install packages), composer.json and composer.lock. Change vendor/package appropriately.

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

Obviously, you'll need to remove references to that package before composer update

when you install any package/module using composer, at that time composer will add the reference into composer.json you can check there your module name. so if you want to remove that module from composer.json, you have to run **composer remove vendor/package**

Comment: not understood clearly, an you help me with it please

Comment: when you install any package/module using composer, at that time composer will add reference into composer.json you can check there you module name. so if you want to remove that module from composer.json, you have two option either run composer remove **YOUR MODULE NAME** or remove from composer.json file